# jhipster generator to create JPA Entity representing nested documents in MongoDb collection

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, jhipster

I am using jhipster with MongoDB. How can we define JPA Entity representing nested document in MongoDb collection using "yo jhipster:entity"

eg:

{
   _id: "joe",
   name: "Joe Bookreader",
   addresses: [
                {
                  street: "123 Fake Street",
                  city: "Faketon",
                  state: "MA",
                  zip: "12345"
                },
                {
                  street: "1 Some Other Street",
                  city: "Boston",
                  state: "MA",
                  zip: "12345"
                }
              ]
 }